# list AWS SCP policies attached to an account

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

Is there anyway I can get a list of all scp policies that is attached to particular account. I have many account in AWS organization and wanted make list of scp policies attached to each individual account. Below python function is working but only showing default AWS managed scp policy however there are many custom SCP policies (inherited policies) attached that it is not listing. Am I doing something wrong?

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='saml')
response = session.client('organizations', region_name='us-east-1')

scp = response.list_policies_for_target(TargetId='xxxxxxxxxxxx', Filter='SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY')
```

With this I am getting only below output.

```
$ python test_lambda.py
[{'Arn': 'arn:aws:organizations::aws:policy/service_control_policy/p-FullAWSAccess',
  'AwsManaged': True,
  'Description': 'Allows access to every operation',
  'Id': 'p-FullAWSAccess',
  'Name': 'FullAWSAccess',
  'Type': 'SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY'}]
```

Comment: Those policies might not come into the list because the are inherited, not attached. Here is complete documentation -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_info-operations.html

Comment: ok looking into the docs. thanks @AnkushJain